Not able to download the JDBC sink plugin in Confluent Kafka Connect
I am working on a project in which I need to pull data from kafka topics and push it into the mysql database. I have seen alot of tutorials on youtube but most of the tutorials are outdated or 4 years old.
I have gone through their official channel tutorials but I don't want to use the confluent cloud. I want to run a single instance just for development.
Through their docs I have found this docker compose filewhich is 3 years old.
Going through the docker compose file I saw the command to download the plugins using confluent-hub like below:
confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:1.7.0
I want to download the jdbc sink driver but not able to get the id like this debezium/debezium-connector-mysql. May anyone knows from where I can get the id for jdbc like this? I have gone through the confluent hub but not able to find such id.
Note: I am running this on Windows 11, if anyone knows any better ways (latest way) to setup the Kafka connect on windows for local development then please let me know
Thanks


most of the tutorials are outdated

I've been using Kafka for 8 years. Nothing you've found should be outdated. Since it hasn't changed.

this docker compose filewhich is 3 years old

Again, processes haven't changed. There have been new Kafka and Confluent Platform releases, which improve Connect API, and Zookeeper is now deprecated, but Connect still is mostly the same... Kafka is very good with backwards compatibility


You should reach out to Confluent Support for missing documentation. At the bottom of every docs page there's a feedback button/link.

I've noticed the same, but  the ID for Debezium connector hasn't changed.

confluent-hub CLI is deprecated. https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker/issues/47#issue-2606839427



setup the Kafka connect on windows for local development

You'd setup an IDE for this with a dependency on org.apache.kafka:connect-api
